# GHC: insert compilation date

Tags: haskell, ghc

I thought there would already be a question about this, but I can't find one.

I want my program to print out the date it was compiled on. What's the easiest way to set that up?

I can think of several possibilities, but none of them are what you'd call "easy". Ideally I'd like to be able to just do `ghc --make Foo` and have `Foo` print out the compilation date each time I run it.

Various non-easy possibilities that spring to mind:

- Learn Template Haskell. Figure out how to use `Data.Time` to fetch today's date. Find a way how to transform that into a string. (Now my program requires TH in order to work. I also need to convince it to recompile that module every time, otherwise I get the compilation date for that module [which never changes] rather than the whole program.)
- Write a shell script that generates a tiny Haskell module containing the system date. (Now I have to use that shell script rather than compile my program directly. Also, shell scripting on Windows leaves *much* to be desired!)
- Sit down and write some Haskell code which generates a tiny Haskell module containing the date. (More portable than previous idea - but still requires extra build steps or the date printed will be incorrect.)
- There might be some way to do this through Cabal - but do I really want to package up this little program just to get a date facility?

Does anybody have any simpler suggestions?

Comment: Alias ghc to something equivalent to ``ghc -DNOW="\"`date`\""`` (no idea how that would look for a Windows shell), and in your module use `{-# LANGUAGE CPP #-}` and `now = NOW` for the date string. Ugly hack, might just be ugly enough to push you to a cleaner alternative that takes more work.

Comment: @DanielFischer Apparently the Windows shell lacks any capability to set a variable from a command's output. Instead, you must use a hack involving `SET /P VAR=`, which reads text from stdin. If you pipe command output to a file, then pipe it back in, you can achieve the effect you want... but JESUS!! >_<

Comment: Oh, wow. Doesn't even PowerShell have that capability?

Comment: @DanielFischer PowerShell may, yes. But I don't have that installed. It seems easier to write a tiny Haskell script to generate the necessary output.

Comment: Yep. That seems much easier then.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Using Template Haskell for this is relatively simple.
You just need to:

1. Run IO action within Template Haskell monad:

   ```
   runIO :: IO a -> Exp a
   ```
2. Then create a string literal with:

   ```
   stringE :: String -> ExpQ
   ```
3. Put a whole expression within a quasiquote.

   ```
   $( ... )
   ```

This program will print time of its compilation:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
import Language.Haskell.TH
import Data.Time

main = print $(stringE =<< runIO (show `fmap` Data.Time.getCurrentTime))
```

You may put the relevant fragment into a module that imports all other modules to make sure it is recompiled.

Or take current revision information from your versioning system. See: [TemplateHaskell and IO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713418/templatehaskell-and-io)

Comment: What a great first answer! Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: This does seem to be just about the cleanest solution. The version string is used in several different places, so I'd put this code in a separate module. The only problem I foresee is getting the version module recompiled every time; perhaps I could use TH to "touch" the source file each time or something?

Comment: MathematicalOrchid: That's why I suggested that this module imports all other toplevel modules. Or one could put this code in `main` module. Then it is always recompiled. The other solution has the same problem, and trying to "touch" the source file could seem dirtier solution for some.

Comment: As of 2023, we have [`githash`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/githash) package that does the thing.

It is useful when you want details like Git commit hash and choose your own date format.

If you really just want a date and time, you may prefer Nick's answer below.

It is also worth noting that `stack` now recompiles Template Haskell modules each time it is called.

Answer (score 10):

The preprocessor helpfully defines `__DATE__` and `__TIME__` macros (just like in C), so this works:

```
{-# LANGUAGE CPP #-}
main = putStrLn (__DATE__ ++ " " ++ __TIME__)
```

This is probably simpler than Michal's suggestion of Template Haskell, but doesn't let you choose the format of the date.

Comment: of course, once you get the date in the program as a literal, you can mangle that however you like.

Comment: I was hoping this might be the case - but I couldn't find any mention of it in the documentation. Also, is there a reason why writing `"__DATE__"` doesn't work, but `__DATE__` on its own does?

Comment: GHC just calls the C preprocessor, so you'll find the predefined macros documented there. The only useful ones are `__DATE__`, `__TIME__`, `__FILE__` (the source file name) and `__LINE__` (the source file line number) - the last two are useful for defining an error macro that includes the source location.

As for why `"__DATE__"` doesn't work, the preprocessor doesn't expand macros inside a string literal. Besides, `__DATE__` on its own already expands to a string literal.